# I just downloaded the Arduino IDE and it doesn't compile any code

Tags: arduino-uno, avr

FQBN: arduino:avr:uno

```
Using board 'uno' from platform in folder: C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6

Detecting libraries used...
C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6\cores\arduino -IC:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6\variants\standard C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\249E86D7CFF632627E003BB52C94264B\sketch\Blink.ino.cpp -o nul
Generating function prototypes...
C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6\cores\arduino -IC:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\avr\1.8.6\variants\standard C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\249E86D7CFF632627E003BB52C94264B\sketch\Blink.ino.cpp -o C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Temp\43183129\sketch_merged.cpp
C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\builtin\tools\ctags\5.8-arduino11/ctags -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Temp\43183129\sketch_merged.cpp
Compiling sketch...
"C:\\Users\\Kareem\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10607 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\\Users\\Kareem\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.6\\cores\\arduino" "-IC:\\Users\\Kareem\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\hardware\\avr\\1.8.6\\variants\\standard" "C:\\Users\\Kareem\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\249E86D7CFF632627E003BB52C94264B\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp" -o "C:\\Users\\Kareem\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\249E86D7CFF632627E003BB52C94264B\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp.o"
Compiling libraries...
Compiling core...
Using precompiled core: C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\cores\arduino_avr_uno_06fe87695d748aefc72866d7f296b9a5\core.a
Linking everything together...
"C:\\Users\\Kareem\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\arduino\\tools\\avr-gcc\\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p -o "C:\\Users\\Kareem\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\249E86D7CFF632627E003BB52C94264B/Blink.ino.elf" "C:\\Users\\Kareem\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\249E86D7CFF632627E003BB52C94264B\\sketch\\Blink.ino.cpp.o" "C:\\Users\\Kareem\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\249E86D7CFF632627E003BB52C94264B/..\\..\\cores\\arduino_avr_uno_06fe87695d748aefc72866d7f296b9a5\\core.a" "-LC:\\Users\\Kareem\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\arduino\\sketches\\249E86D7CFF632627E003BB52C94264B" -lm
c:/users/kareem/appdata/local/arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/avr-gcc/7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/7.3.0/../../../../avr/lib/avr5/crtatmega328p.o:(.init9+0x0): undefined reference to `main'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1
```

Comment: Looks like precompiled core doesn't contain main or something...

Comment: delete `C:\Users\Kareem\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\cores\arduino_avr_uno_06fe87695d748aefc72866d7f296b9a5\core.a` and try again

Comment: @hcheung .cpp.ino is created by the Arduino builder

Comment: I have same problem. I can find "main.cpp.o" in core.a. it's confused